# Blank screen using Ionic and NgMap module

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need some help over here, I'm trying to load 'NgMap' module, to render a Google Map in my application builded with Ionic Framework. I get the right response in my browser, without any error in my developer console, but when I emulate the App in Android or going to Ionic View with my iPhone, i get a blank screen. I don't know what I am doing wrong, i'll appreciate any help. Here is my code:

index.html:

```
    <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js"></script>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ui.router', 'starter.controllers', 'ngMap'])
```

map.html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Get Directions">
<ion-content data-tap-disabled="true">
    <div class="row nomargin">
        <div class="col text-center">
            <h4>7810 NW 98th Street </br> Miami Lakes, FL 33016</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row nomargin">
        <div class="col">
            <button class="button button-block map-button">
              <h4>Open in Maps</h4>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row nomargin nopadding">
        <div class="col nomargin nopadding">
            <map class="map-height" center="25.862359, -80.324403" zoom="13">
                <marker position="[25.862359, -80.324403]" />
            </map>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

As I said, I'm not getting any error in my browser and the map render properly, but in the emulator or Ionic View, appears a white screen. Thanks in advance.

PD: Sorry for my awful english

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. I installed [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/) in my case the error was that the App running in 'Android emulator' could not find the two external libraries used for 'ngMap':

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="//rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js"></script>
```

Screenshot of the error caught by using GapDebug:

[image: screenshot of the error in GapDebug]

I had to change the tags to include "https(http can also work)" to make it work:

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js"></script>
```

Changing these links also fixed the "Ionic View- Blank page" issue.